# Laravel: Usar los datos del login para poder cargar el perfil del usuario

Tags: laravel, login, vuejs

estoy haciendo una aplicación en laravel con vuejs. Quiero leer los datos del usuario autenticado y usar su id para hacer una consulta a la base de datos y traer toda la información respectiva
Estoy usando templates y en el archivo principal tengo lo siguiente

```
<meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::user() }}">
```

y en mi archivo perfil.vue tengo lo siguiente

```
<script>  
  var usuarioId = JSON.parse(document.head.querySelector('meta[name="user"]').content).id;
```

ya verifiqué por consola que si lee el id del usuario.
Tengo una función con axios que usa ese id para traer los datos

```
methods : {
  verAlumno(id){...}
```

y cargo la función respectiva

```
mounted() {
  this.verAlumno(this.usuarioId);
```

y al ejecutar la app me sale el siguiente error en la consola

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at app.js:10405

ya intenté declarar la variable asi también

```
export default {
  data (){
    return {
      usuarioId : JSON.parse(document.head.querySelector('meta[name="user"]').content).id,
```

y sale el mismo error. Pero si le asigno un valor numérico a la misma variable ahi sale todo correctamente.

Asumo que debe ser algo sencillo, pero ya he intentado muchas cosas y nada me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Si solo vas a usar el id, puede imprimir solo el id

```
<meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::id() }}">
```

Si por el contrario necesitas todo el objeto auth, debes cambiar las llaves de esta forma

```
<meta name="user" content="{!! json_encode(Auth::user()) !!}">
```

Desde ahi ya puedes tomar el JSON y hacer parse